# Url rewriting in play framework

Tags: playframework

I am going to develop a cms system which have different article with user specified path. These path are not specified  in routes files. then how to use this user specified path in application.

Comment: Here are a few routing examples, have a look at : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaRouting and if this does not solve your problem, then you could also experiment with the router dsl for fine tuned custom routes https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaRoutingDsl

Answer (score 0):

Use a route like this

```
GET /articles/*path    controllers.YourController.article(path: String)
```

This will accept whatever you pass to it. So if you controller is defined like this:

```
public Result article(String path) {
    return ok("Got: " + path);
}
```

accessing something like `/articles/some/article` will return "Got: some/article".

You can then load the content as required (ex from the database)

Comment: I can't start with /article/* , Only I can use user specified path

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario I found a solution that, from error handler we can read the url and redirect to specific file.  ex: when hitting this url /articles/ the error handler will throw 404 error, there you can redirect to your customized resource.

Thannks.